# How to connect LCD backlight wires

Tags: reverse-engineering, monitor, ccfl

I have bad caps in my LCD monitor. While taking it apart, I disconnected the LCD backlight wires to get to the power supply. I blame bad product design and my own stupidity for not checking how the wires were connected. It looked [something like this](http://510x.se/notes/posts/Repair_LCD_monitor_with_bad_capacitors/img_1490.jpg), except in my case one of the connectors is rotated 90 degrees. Since the connectors are the same, I'm now afraid of switching the two cables and killing the backlight or the electronics.

How can I find out where to put each plug?

Edit: Based on the advice by Rohat Kılıç, I popped the wires in and the monitor not only did not explode, but it now also works as expected. Another piece of consumer electronics saved from going into the junkyard, yay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the backlight cables are paired and terminated with the same connectors then most likely the panel has CFL (Fluorescent) backlight. You could also check twice for a high voltage danger icon on the PCB. So it will not be a problem to connect even in reversed order.

Comment: Yes, it is most definitely a CFL-backlit monitor, I forgot to mention that in the question. I'll wait for some time before accepting the answer in case somebody else has a different opinion, but you are probably right. Thanks!